# How can Notepad++ be extended as an IDE for R?

Tags: ide, r, package, notepad++

I am working with NppToR as an extension allowing the use of notepad++ to be an IDE for R.

But there are a few features I didn't yet see implemented (I compiled the list from another IDE solution, which is not open source) :

**Object Browser** - Allow users to see all the data and function objects that are available, including those in loaded and installed R packages.  Context menus provide the capability to quickly edit and plot data or load a package.

**Full-featured Visual Debugger** - Debug R scripts, with step-in, step-over, and step-out capability, allowing users to inspect and modify R objects as they are debugging

**A Visual Solution Explorer** - Organize, view, add, remove, rearrange, and deploy R scripts. Users can create their own Project Templates for automatic creation of a set of customized scripts for a new R project. Dockable, Floating, and Tabbed Tool Windows. for Creating personally customized workspaces.

**Enhanced Help** - Complete search capabilities and hover-over tooltips for functions and data objects.

**R Code Snippets** - Automatically generate fill-in-the-blank sections of R code for a variety of analyses. Tooltip help gives guidance in filling out the snippet.

Any Idea on how to get some of these already in notepad++ through some other noteps++ extensions or R packages ?

Thanks,
Tal

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of the previous questions about recommendations for an IDE to be used with R. Unfortunately the search feature here is a tad weak.

Comment: Here's the earlier post on IDE for R: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439059/best-ide-texteditor-for-r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notepad++ isn't really configured to offer these types of features. You'll do better to explore StatET + Eclipse or ESS (Emacs speaks statistics).

Links:

- [StatET](http://www.walware.de/goto/statet)
- [StatET install guide](http://www.splusbook.com/R_Eclipse_StatET.pdf) (PDF)
- [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/)

Comment: Of course. Run, don't walk, to Vincent Goulet's page with a single install of R + ESS + Auctex ready to run on Windoze (and one for OS X) -- see http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/ressources/emacs/.

Comment: If you are used to Windows you may find StatET easier to learn. I'm in windows most of the time and slip between notepad++, Sublime, and Eclipse+StatET quite a lot. My experimentation with ESS ended 15 seconds after I muttered to myself, "how the hell do I print from this thing?" ;)

Comment: @JD: How about mark a region with the mouse and select File->Print Region? And File->Print Buffer prints the whole buffer.

Comment: @dirk: um.. hey look! is that a bunny over there?!?!?  (anything to distract from my idiocy)

Comment: After seeing the reply of the developer, I suspect your answer is the right one...

http://sourceforge.net/projects/npptor/forums/forum/880832/topic/3557724

(e.g: notepad++ good for starting out, not for long term mature statistical programming)

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, there is a great package RKWard, which takes care of all the issues that Notepad++ is missing.

Unfotunately, I was unable to make it run under Windows (it says it is missing a dll)

So I am using Notepad++ as my development environment and RStudio for runtime environment

Answer (score 0):

Actually, with NppToR, it becomes a real blast!  No need for RStudio - although if you have a big screen, RStudio is still a great runtime environment