# Setting default "open" behavior of a `.R` file in Windows?

Tags: r, s-plus

Q: In Windows, how can I set `.R` files to open by default in the R Editor? A bonus would be if they opened AND set the workspace to the directory in which they live.

Windows is able to open `.ssc` files in the Splus script editor by default. Not sure why I can't get the same behavior for `.R` files in the R Editor.

I've already tried *Right Click -> Open With -> Choose Default Program* and gone through `R.exe` and other similar options. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume what is happening is that when you associate R with .R files, R opens them and runs them rather than opening them in the editor.

There's an easy solution, but it doesn't involve the R editor: Use a real text editor.  There are quite a few, but I'm partial to jEdit or Eclipse with STAT/ET (which offers a full IDE), or the new RStudio.

Other suggestions [have been posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439059/best-ide-texteditor-for-r) in the past.

Comment: I'm trying to postpone fumbling around with a new text editor until the end of my current project. When I do upgrade, I think I'll be going with RStudio. Looks slick.

Answer (score 0):

Set the default program to Tinn-R ( or Emacs and use ESS. Here's a handy bundled Emacs for Windows.

http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/ressources/emacs/windows )