# R sometimes does not save my history

Tags: r

I have a program in R.  Sometimes when I save history, they do not write into my history file.  I lost some histories a few times and this really drive me crazy.

Any recommendation on how to avoid this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First check your working directory (`getwd()`). `savehistory()` saves the history in the current working directory. And to be honest, you better specify the filename, as the default is `.History`. Say :

```
savehistory('C:/MyWorkingDir/MySession.RHistory')
```

which allows you to :

```
loadhistory('C:/MyWorkingDir/MySession.RHistory')
```

So the history is not lost, it's just in a place and under a name you weren't aware of. See also `?history`.

To clarify : the history is no more than a text file containing all commands of that current session. So it's a nice log of what you've done, but I almost never use it. I construct my "analysis log" myself by using scripts, as hinted in another answer.

Comment: The help file for history has a "must have" feature that automatically saves history via the .Last function stored in a .RProfile. I rely on this alot!

Comment: Joris: I agree. It is better to use my own script editor. R's history panel washes down every command, whatever wrong or not.

Answer (score 1):

@Stedy has provided a workable solution to your immediate question.  I would encourage you to learn how to use .R files and a proper text editor, or use an integrated development environment (see [this SO page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439059/best-ide-texteditor-for-r) for suggestions).  You can then `source()` in your .R file so that you can consistently replicate your analysis.

For even better replicability, invest the time into learning Sweave.  You'll be glad you did.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Rstudio_Desktop/history_database file - it stores every command for any working directory.

See here for more details [How to save the whole sequence of commands from a specific day to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22664381/)

Comment: This might be the most useful thing I've learned in the last 2 years. Thank you so much for this answer... Seriously just saved me days of work due to a RHistory file that wasn't updating.

Answer (score 0):

Logging your console on a regular basis to **dated* files is handy.  The package `TeachingDemos` has a great function for logging your console session, but it's written as a singleton, which is problematic for automatic logging, since you wouldn't be able to use that function to create teaching demo's if you use it for logging.   I re-used that function using a bit of meta-programming to make a copy of that functionality that I include in the [`.First`](http://www.statmethods.net/interface/customizing.html) function in my local [`.Rprofile`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html), as follows:

```
.Logger <- (function(){

    # copy local versions of the txtStart,
    locStart  <-  TeachingDemos::txtStart
    locStop  <-  TeachingDemos::txtStop
    locR2txt  <-  TeachingDemos:::R2txt

    # creat a local environment and link it to each function
    .e.  <-  new.env()
    .e.$R2txt.vars <- new.env()
    environment(locStart) <- .e.
    environment(locStop) <- .e.
    environment(locR2txt) <- .e.


    # reference the local functions in the calls to `addTaskCallback`
    # and `removeTaskCallback`
    body(locStart)[[length(body(locStart))-1]] <- 
        substitute(addTaskCallback(locR2txt, name='locR2txt'))
    body(locStop)[[2]] <- 
        substitute(removeTaskCallback('locR2txt'))


    list(start=function(logDir){
                op <- options()
                locStart(file.path(logDir,format(Sys.time(), "%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S.txt")),
                         results=FALSE)
                options(op)
    }, stop = function(){
                op <- options()
                locStop()
                options(op)
    })

})()



.First <- function(){

    if( interactive() ){

        # JUST FOR FUN
        cat("\nWelcome",Sys.info()['login'],"at", date(), "\n")
        if('fortunes' %in% utils::installed.packages()[,1] )
            print(fortunes::fortune())

        # CONSTANTS
        TIME  <-  Sys.time()
        logDir  <- "~/temp/Rconsole.logfiles" 

        # CREATE THE TEMP DIRECORY IF IT DOES NOT ALREADY EXIST
        dir.create(logDir, showWarnings = FALSE)

        # DELETE FILES OLDER THAN A WEEK
        for(fname in list.files(logDir))
            if(difftime(TIME, 
                        file.info(file.path(logDir,fname))$mtime,
                        units="days") > 7 ) 
                file.remove(file.path(logDir,fname))

        # sink() A COPY OF THE TERMINAL OUTPUT TO A DATED LOG FILE
        if('TeachingDemos' %in% utils::installed.packages()[,1] )
            .Logger$start(logDir)
        else 
            cat('install package `TeachingDemos` to enable console logging')
    }

}

.Last  <-  function(){
    .Logger$stop()
}
```

This causes a copy of the terminal contents to be copied to a dated log file.  The nice thing about having dated files is that if you use multiple R sessions the log files won't conflict, unless you start multiple interactive sessions in the same second).