# Retrieving Variable Declaration

Tags: r, variables

How can I find how did I first declare a certain variable when I am a few hundred
lines down from where I first declared it. For example, I have declared the following:

```
a <- c(vectorA,vectorB,vectorC)
```

and now I want to see how I declared it. How can I do that?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. If by declare, you mean "what's in this". Perhaps you're looking for something like `?str`... str(a)

Comment: I want retrieve "a<-c(vectorA,vectorB,vectorC)" - the way how I first declared it, if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try using the `history` command:

```
history(pattern = "a <-")
```

to try to find lines in your history where you assigned something to the variable `a`. I think this matches exactly, though, so you may have to watch out for spaces.

Indeed, if you type `history` at the command line, it doesn't appear to be doing anything fancier than saving the current history in a tempfile, loading it back in using `readLines` and then searching it using `grep`. It ought to be fairly simple to modify that function to include more functionality...for example, this modification will cause it to return the matching lines so you can store it in a variable:

```
myHistory <- function (max.show = 25, reverse = FALSE, pattern, ...) 
{
    file1 <- tempfile("Rrawhist")
    savehistory(file1)
    rawhist <- readLines(file1)
    unlink(file1)
    if (!missing(pattern)) 
        rawhist <- unique(grep(pattern, rawhist, value = TRUE, 
            ...))
    nlines <- length(rawhist)
    if (nlines) {
        inds <- max(1, nlines - max.show):nlines
        if (reverse) 
            inds <- rev(inds)
    }
    else inds <- integer()
    #file2 <- tempfile("hist")
    #writeLines(rawhist[inds], file2)
    #file.show(file2, title = "R History", delete.file = TRUE)
    rawhist[inds]
}
```

Comment: +1 I use a vi-style CLI, but this would be very handy for many users.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you're using the default R console. If you're on Windows, you can File -> Save history and open the file in your fav text browser, or you can use function `savehistory()` (see `help(savehistory)`).

What you need to do is get a (good) IDE, or at least a decent text editor. You will benevit from code folding, syntax coloring and much more. There's a plethora of choices, from Tinn-R, VIM, ESS, Eclipse+StatET, RStudio or RevolutionR [among others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439059/best-ide-texteditor-for-r).

Comment: I should say I am using R on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `grep 'a<-' .Rhistory` from terminal (assuming that you've `cd`d to your working directory). ESS has several very useful history-searching functions, like `(comint-history-isearch-backward-regexp)` - binded to `M-r` by default.

For further info, consult ESS manual: http://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html

Answer (score 0):

When you define a function, R stores the source code of the function (preserving formatting and comments) in an attribute named "source". When you type the name of the function, you will get this content printed.

But it doesn't do this with variables. You can deparse a variable, which generates an expression that will produce the variable's value but this doesn't need to be the original expression. For example when you have `b <- c(17, 5, 21)`, `deparse(b)` will produce the string `"c(17, 5, 21)"`.

In your example, however, the result wouldn't be "c(vectorA,vectorB,vectorC)", it would be an expression that produces the combined result of your three vectors.