# Can I move the cursor to revise in R?

Tags: r, cursor

I input something into the R console:

```
> ta <- function(x,y){  
+ x=x+2  
+ y=y+1  
+
```

Now  my cursor is on the fourth line, I found it's `x=x+1`, not `x=x+2`.
Can I move my cursor onto the second line to revise `x=x+2` into `x=x+1`?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware, you can't do what you describe. What you can do is press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel entering into the console and start afresh writing it in.

Are you using an IDE? Or are you writing directly into the RGui? If the latter, I heartily recommend using [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.org/). It will make your life a lot easier. You'll be able to to enter text into one window and then send it into the R console when you're ready.

Alternatively. R does have an editor (File >  New script) which you can use to send lines, or you can even use a txt file off to the side and only send lines when you're ready.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no way to edit the function while R is still waiting for you to close the function call. So first, I think you need to finish writing your function by typing `}`. Once completed, you can then do one of a few things, all of which are outlined in good detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458013/what-ways-are-there-to-edit-a-function-in-r). I won't bother regurgitating those perfectly good answers, but do recommend you check them out. Finally, if you aren't currently using an IDE to help develop your R code, that will make your life much easier. Which IDE will be best for you is also quite subjective, but has been covered on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439059/best-ide-texteditor-for-r) before. FWIW, I've had good luck with [RStudio](http://rstudio.org/) which is platform independent and all that good jazz...your miles may vary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running R from a terminal, you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> to cancel your entry and start over.