# Under R,regarding getting the list of the commands previously typed

Tags: r

Under R, is there a way to list all of the commands that have previously been typed?

Answer (score 7):

Yes there is.

```
history(max.show=Inf)
```

Comment: Note that this is the "currently available" history -- `R_HISTSIZE` defaults to storing only 512 lines, you could use `Sys.setenv(R_HISTSIZE=10000)` if you wanted to go crazy ...

Answer (score 2):

[IDEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439059/best-ide-texteditor-for-r) for R often support this feature in a panel.  RStudio, for instance, has a history tab from which you can send a previous command to the console or to your source file with a click.  I believe others are similar functionality as well.