# What core packages should a professional R developer have, and why?

Tags: unit-testing, debugging, r, development-environment

What are the specific utilities that can help R developers code and debug more efficiently?

I'm looking to set up an R development environment, and would like an overview of the tools that would be useful to me in crafting a unit testing infrastructure with code coverage, debugging, generation of package files and help files and maybe UML modeling.

**Note:** Please justify your answers with reasons and examples based on your experience with the tools you recommend. **Don't just link**.

#### Related

- [Recommendations for Windows text editor for R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173463/recommendations-for-windows-text-editor-for-r)
- [What IDEs are available for R in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097367/what-ides-are-available-for-r-in-linux)
- [Tools Commonly used to Program in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818521/tools-commonly-used-to-program-in-r)

Comment: For debugging, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1882734/what-is-your-favorite-r-debugging-trick  

For IDE, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173463/recommendations-for-windows-text-editor-for-r and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097367/what-ides-are-available-for-r-in-linux

Comment: I'm a bit suprised no one has mentioned RStudio (http://wwww.rstudio.org)

Comment: @Brandon : RStudio is great, but as yet not enough for developing packages. It will get there for sure, I love what they did until now.

Comment: **before casting a vote to close this question again, please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100617 - thank you** If you want to have a say in the discussion, take it to meta. One of the things borderline questions do is generate noise in the comments. I will not allow that. Discuss on meta, not here.

Comment: I've tried to edit this into something specific ("recommend all the tools I'll ever want" isn't a question anyone can answer). I've also closed / merged several other similar questions to try and create a set of useful r-tools posts here. Please be mindful of the **Note** when answering - if this devolves into a list of unjustified links and/or self-promotion, it will be closed and deleted without mercy - your goal should be to aid users who *can* use Google but need expert advice in making sense of the results, not simply a snapshot list of the ever-changing landscape of tools out there.

Comment: @Shog9 Thank you for your input and editing of the Q and related Qs. It is much appreciated - as is that of Robert Harvey.

Answer (score 50):

I have written way too many packages, so to keep things manageable I've invested a lot of time in infrastructure packages: packages that help me make my code more robust and help make it easier for others to use.  These include:

- `roxygen2` (with Manuel Eugster and Peter Danenberg), which allows you to keep documentation next to the function it documents, which it makes it much more likely that I'll keep it up to date. `roxygen2` also has a number of new features designed to minimise documentation duplication: templates (`@template`), parameter inheritance (`@inheritParams`), and function families (`@family`) to name a few.
- `testthat` automates the testing of my code.  This is becoming more and more important as I have less and less time to code: automated tests remember how the function should work, even when I don't.
- `devtools` automates many common development tasks (as Andrie mentioned). The eventual goal for `devtools` is for it to act like `R CMD check` that runs continuously in the background and notifies you the instance that something goes wrong.
- `profr`, particularly the unreleased [interactive explorer](http://vimeo.com/24475118), makes it easy for me to find bottlenecks in my code.
- `helpr` (with Barret Schloerke), which will soon power http://had.co.nz/ggplot2, provides an elegant html interface to R documentation.

Useful R functions:

- `apropos`: I'm always forgetting the names of useful functions, and `apropos` helps me find them, even if I only remember a fragment

Outside of R:

- I use textmate to edit R (and other) files, but I don't think it's really that important. Pick one and learn all it's nooks and crannies.
- Spend some time to learn the command line. Anything you can do to automate any part of your workflow will pay off in the long run. Running R from the command line leads to a natural process where each project has it's own instance of R; I often have 2-5 instances of R running at a time.
- Use version control.  I like `git` and [github](http://github.com/hadley/).  Again, it doesn't matter exactly which system you use, but master it!

Things I wish R had:

- code coverage tools
- a dependency management framework like rake or jake
- better memory profiling tools
- a metadata standard for describing data frames (and other data sources)
- better tools for describing and rendering tables in a variety of output formats
- a package for markdown rendering

Comment: Interesting - especially the metadata standard for describing data frames. This is not that hard - at least an initial cut that takes care of the 80%. What usage scenarions are you thinking of ? One idea might be a metadata data frame (which has strict semantics) that can be attached to the data source. Thoughts ?

Comment: Is that link correct: `helpr` will replace `ggplot2`?

Comment: The command line bit can't be overstated.  One can increase their productivity by an order of magnitude by have basic unix CLI knowledge.

Comment: @Iterator - helpr will power the ggplot2 website, not replace ggplot2.

Comment: @Krishna - I'm thinking more of an external format like [qnch](http://eagereyes.org/blog/2009/qnch-data-description-language-for-tabular-data.html).

Comment: For meta data information for dataframes can we use comment(dataframe$column) to annotate each column with proper format?

Comment: Also: I flagged the question for more review after it was closed (a low/negative-utility community-adverse action, in my opinion).  Can't this be made into a community wiki?  Intention is positive: although flagging may look negative - my intent is not to affect the OP, but the closing.

Answer (score 48):

As I recall this has been asked before and my answer remains the same:  Emacs.

Emacs can

- do just about anything you want to do with R thanks to [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org), including

  - code execution of various snippets (line, region, function, buffer, ...)
  - inspection of workspaces,
  - display of variables,
  - multiple R sessions and easy switching between them
  - transcript mode for re-running (parts of) previous sessions
  - access to the help system
  - and much more
- handles Latex with similar ease via the AucTex mode, which helps Sweave for R
- has modes for whichever other programming languages you combine with R, be it C/C++, Python, shell, SQL, ... covering automatic indentation and colour highlighting
- can access databases with sql-* mode
- can work remotely with tramp mode: access remote files as if they were local (uses ssh/scp)
- can be ran as a daemon which makes it stateful so you can reconnect to your same Emacs session, be it on the workstation under X11 (or equivalent) or remotely via ssh (with or without X11) or screen.
- has [org-mode](http://www.orgmode.org), which together with babel, provides a powerful sweave alternative as discussed [in this paper discussing *workflow apps* for (social) scientists](http://www.kieranhealy.org/files/misc/workflow-apps.pdf)
- can run a shell via `M-x shell` and/or `M-x eshell`, has nice directory access functionality with dired mode, has ssh mode for remote access
- interfaces all source code repositories with ease via specific modes (eg psvn for svn)
- is cross-platform just like R so you have similar user-interface experiences on all relevant operating systems
- is widely used, widely available and under active development for both code and extensions, see the emacswiki.org site for the latter
- `<tongueInCheek>`is not Eclipse and does not require Java`</tongueInCheek>`

You can of course combine it with whichever CRAN packages you like:  RUnit or testthat, the different profiling support packages, the debug package, ...

Additional tools that are useful:

- `R CMD check` really is your friend as this is what CRAN uses to decide whether you are "in or out"; use it and trust it
- the `tests/` directory can offer a simplified version of unit tests by saving to-be-compared against output (from a prior `R CMD check` run), this is useful but proper unit tests are better
- particularly for packages with object code, I prefer to launch fresh R sessions and [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) makes that easy: `r -lfoo -e'bar(1, "ab")'` starts an R session, loads the `foo` package and evaluates the given expression (here a function `bar()` with two arguments).  This, combined with `R CMD INSTALL`, provides a full test cycle.

Comment: Do use any unit testing and code coverage tool? what about other packages and scripts that you use to help you code efficiently?

Comment: If you look at my packages, you will see fairly extensive use of RUnit.  I do not deploy any explicit code coverage tools.

Comment: What are the profiling tools that you use then? :)

Comment: I talked about that in some detail (and with examples) in my 'Introduction to HPC with R' presentations, see my site for pdf copies.

Comment: Here is the link to that talk in case anybody needs it http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/papers/ismNov2009introHPCwithR.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link, Mark, but there are also slightly newer versions in the same directory.

Answer (score 9):

Knowledge of, and ability to use, the basic R debugging tools is an essential first step in learning to quickly debug R code. If you know how to use the basic tools you can debug code anywhere without having to need all the extra tools provided in add-on packages.

`traceback()` allows you to see the call stack leading to an error

```
foo <- function(x) {
    d <- bar(x)
    x[1]
}
bar <- function(x) {
    stopifnot(is.matrix(x))
    dim(x)
}
foo(1:10)
traceback()
```

yields:

```
> foo(1:10)
Error: is.matrix(x) is not TRUE
> traceback()
4: stop(paste(ch, " is not ", if (length(r) > 1L) "all ", "TRUE", 
       sep = ""), call. = FALSE)
3: stopifnot(is.matrix(x))
2: bar(x)
1: foo(1:10)
```

So we can clearly see that the error happened in function `bar()`; we've narrowed down the scope of bug hunt. But what if the code generates warnings, not errors? That can be handled by turning warnings into errors via the `warn` option:

```
options(warn = 2)
```

will turn warnings into errors. You can then use `traceback()` to track them down.

Linked to this is getting R to recover from an error in the code so you can debug what went wrong. `options(error = recover)` will drop us into a debugger frame whenever an error is raised:

```
> options(error = recover)
> foo(1:10)
Error: is.matrix(x) is not TRUE

Enter a frame number, or 0 to exit   

1: foo(1:10)
2: bar(x)
3: stopifnot(is.matrix(x))

Selection: 2
Called from: bar(x)
Browse[1]> x
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
Browse[1]> is.matrix(x)
[1] FALSE
```

You see we can drop into each frame on the call stack and see how the functions were called, what the arguments are etc. In the above example, we see that `bar()` was passed a vector not a matrix, hence the error. `options(error = NULL)` resets this behaviour to normal.

Another key function is `trace()`, which allows you to insert debugging calls into an existing function. The benefit of this is that you can tell R to debug from a particular line in the source:

```
> x <- 1:10; y <- rnorm(10)
> trace(lm, tracer = browser, at = 10) ## debug from line 10 of the source
Tracing function "lm" in package "stats"
[1] "lm"
> lm(y ~ x)
Tracing lm(y ~ x) step 10 
Called from: eval(expr, envir, enclos)
Browse[1]> n ## must press n <return> to get the next line step
debug: mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame())
Browse[2]> 
debug: if (method == "model.frame") return(mf) else if (method != "qr") warning(gettextf("method = '%s' is not supported. Using 'qr'", 
    method), domain = NA)
Browse[2]> 
debug: if (method != "qr") warning(gettextf("method = '%s' is not supported. Using 'qr'", 
    method), domain = NA)
Browse[2]> 
debug: NULL
Browse[2]> Q
> untrace(lm)
Untracing function "lm" in package "stats"
```

This allows you to insert the debugging calls at the right point in the code without having to step through the proceeding functions calls.

If you want to step through a function as it is executing, then `debug(foo)` will turn on the debugger for function `foo()`, whilst `undebug(foo)` will turn off the debugger.

A key point about these options is that I haven't needed to modify/edit any source code to insert debugging calls etc. I can try things out and see what the problem is directly from the session where there error has occurred.

For a different take on debugging in R, see Mark Bravington's **[debug](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/debug/index.html)** package on CRAN