# How do I open an r script (.R file) in RStudio by double-clicking it in windows

Tags: r, rstudio, rscript

When I double click an R script (.R file) in order to open and edit it, nothing happens.
I expect it to open it in either R or RStudio but it doesn't.

I found a similar (old) question ([Opening a .R file via a double click (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487967/opening-a-r-file-via-a-double-click-windows)) but the solution doesn't work for me.

I have tried:
- right-clicking and explicitly telling it to open it with RStudio
- set it as the default program to associate with this file type
- drag the script into RStudio

Anyone any idea whether it is Windows or R(Studio) related?

Running:
Windows 10 Pro
R version 3.6.1
RStudio version 1.2.1335

Comment: It's a problem with your file associations in windows. I'm not having any issues on the same platform, although running RStudio 1.1.463. Check file associations in windows setting, or try reinstalling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the first comment suggest, it is likely a problem occuring while installing R or Rstudio. This would most likely be fixed by reinstalling Rstudio. If it doesnt i'd suggest checking out [this Rstudio question](https://community.rstudio.com/t/rstudio-file-association-doesnt-work-in-windows-10-enterprise/18225).

Basically, you can manually create using the command prompt (start -> "cmd" -> enter), using

```
assoc .R=rfile
Ftype rfile="C:\Program Files\RStudio\bin\rstudio.exe" %1
```

changing the rstudio directory to the correct directory for your computer.

A less command-prompty solution might be available by following the steps described [in this guide.](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-file-associations-in-windows-2624477) However i did not test the latter approach.

Comment: I checked the file association in Windows, that was set correctly already.
Luckily, reinstalling RStudio fixed the problem. Thanks for your help!